# In-memory cache 200,000 user data at a different machine

Tags: caching, redis, ehcache, in-memory

We have many applications accessing single database. To decrease number of accesses to the database, we are planning to cache 200,000 users and their relevant data in an in-memory cache like Redis, memcached etc.

The cache will be placed at a different machine and every application server will access the cache by network call.

Could anybody confirm that we are following the right approach or suggest a better one?

Comment: Are the application servers on the same physical machine as the single database?

Comment: Database and application server are on different machines. we are using Window 7 server for application and MSsql server for database.we are considering option of Redis or Memcached. most probably we will use memcached since Redis is not production ready on Window

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your scenario. Let's say you have 200,000 users with each user's details (dob, address, name etc) that need to be stored.

**Scenario #1**
Your application server needs *all* the data associated with user for most of the calls it makes to data store.

**Scenario #2**
Your application server needs *some* the data associated with user (sometimes only age, sometimes only dob) for most of the calls it makes to data store.

For scenario #1, Memcache works well. For scenario #2, Redis works very well.

Of course there are many hundred other considerations.

Comment: We will use in-memory cache for both kind of scenarios. Actually we will install cache server(we have decided with Redis) as a standalone application and every application server ( which 7 in number currently , it will increase with time) will access the data from Redis.

Comment: Now Main question i am facing  how should i use redis as standalone. Right now i can think of few options , not sure how effective they are , just few random thought. 1) core java with redis . but we will access Mssql server to populate cache and use scheduling to store data back to database , so would need hibernate for that . considering this 2nd option seems better 2) Apache camel with redis on Jboss app server . here shall i use any j2ee framework to ease out my work i.e. spring  or javaee6. I am still goggling the possible options.  Please suggest a better approach on this

Comment: Given that Redis can persist data to disk, it can be used as a stand-alone. Regarding considerations of various drivers to connect from Java to Redis, please search/ask a different question.
If above answer helped you, accept or upvote or both.